# PHP Parse File, replacing not required items going wrong

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I'm trying to parse each IP line from the following file (loading from the web) and I'm going to store the values in database so i'm looking to put them in to an array.

The file its loading has the following source:

```
12174 in store for taking<hr>221.223.89.99:8909

<br>123.116.123.71:8909

<br>221.10.162.40:8909

<br>222.135.5.38:8909

<br>120.87.121.122:8909

<br>118.77.254.242:8909

<br>218.6.19.14:8909

<br>113.64.124.85:8909

<br>123.118.243.239:8909

<br>124.205.154.181:8909

<br>124.117.13.116:8909

<br>183.7.223.212:8909

<br>112.239.205.245:8909

<br>118.116.235.156:8909

<br>27.16.28.174:8909

<br>222.221.142.59:8909

<br>114.86.40.251:8909

<br>111.225.105.142:8909

<br>115.56.86.62:8909

<br>59.51.108.142:8909

<br>222.219.39.194:8909

<br>114.244.252.246:8909

<br>202.194.148.41:8909

<br>113.94.174.239:8909

<br><hr>total£º 24¡£
```

So I guess I'm looking to take everything between the `<hr>`'s and add each line line by line.

However doing the following doesn't seem to be working (in terms of stripping it the parts i dont' want)

```
<?php
$fileurl = "**MASKED**";

$lines = file($fileurl);

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {

    $line2 = strstr($line, 'taking', 'true');
    $line3 = str_replace($line2, '', $line);
    print_r($line3);

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the values to an array, why not doing that directly inside the loop? I'd do something like this:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if(preg_match("/<br>\d/", $line)) {
        $output[] = substr($line, 4);
    }
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Whilst on the subject, It wont let me in that array add the items to the database, I've tried adding in the foreach to add $output in my mysql_query but it doesn't seem to add it

Comment: MySql can't handle PHP arrays. So, instead of adding to the array, you can do an insert query directly in the loop: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_name (col_name) VALUES ('" . substr($line, 4) . "')");`

Answer (score 1):

Look into PHP function `explode`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

It can take a string, and create an array out of it, by splitting at a specific character. In your case, this might be `<br>`

Also, `trim` function can get rid of the whitespace when needed.